# The value of $I=\int_{|z|=2}z^2\sin\frac{1}{z}dz$?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, complex-integration

I want to get the value of $I=\int_{|z|=2}z^2\sin\frac{1}{z}dz$.

My idea is to let $t=\frac{1}{z}$, then 
$$I=\int_{|z|=2}z^2\sin\frac{1}{z}dz=\int_{|t|=\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\sin t}{t^4}dt=2\pi i \times-\frac{1}{6}=-\frac{\pi i}{3}$$ Is this right?

Comment: It seems clearest to me to give the first few terms of the expansion of $\sin 1/z$, and then to just explicitly use the residue there. But your change of variables would also work.

Comment: Note that changing your question *after* receiving an  answer makes the answer (partially) invalid, and can confuse future readers of the Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result has the wrong sign because you did not take into account that the substitution $t=-\frac{1}{z}$ reverts the orientation of the circle.

You could also apply the residue theorem directly to
$$
 z^2 \sin \frac 1z  = z^2 \left( \frac 1z - \frac{1}{3!z^3} + \ldots \right) = z -\frac{1}{6z} + \ldots
$$
so that 
$$\operatorname{Res}(z^2 \sin \frac 1z, 0) = -\frac 16$$ and therefore
$$
I = 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(z^2 \sin \frac 1z, 0) = - \frac{\pi i}{3} \,.
$$